# Flutter - S/W Keyboard Appears Then Dissapears When App Running on Device Web Browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Flutter App (`Flutter 3.3.7 • channel stable`) written for both mobile devices and web browsers.

App has a `Widget` with `TextField`. The `TextField` uses a `TextEditingController`.

On mobile and tablets, native app runs fine and `TextField` editing works fine using either s/w keyboard or tablet's h/w keyboard.

On a Web browser, web app runs fine and `TextField` editing works fine using computer's h/w keyboard.

On mobile web browser however, web app's `TextField` editing fails. When one clicks on the `TextField` to edit it, the s/w keyboard appears for a fraction of a second and then disappears. No error is thrown so can't see what the issue might be.

The `Widget` with the `TextField` is written like this:

```
class NameWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const NameWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NameWidget> createState() => _NameWidgetState();
}

class _NameWidgetState extends State<NameWidget> {
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textEditingController.text = client.name;
    _textEditingController.addListener(() {
      String name = _textEditingController.text;
      if (validate(name)) {
        client.name = name;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 250,
      height: 60,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
        scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name'),
        maxLength: 9,
        controller: _textEditingController,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

--- UPDATE ---

When testing the `TextField`  widget on a minimal web app with following Widget tree: **MaterialApp->StatefulWidget->Scaffold->Center->NameWidget** then the s/w keyboard works as expected in all situations (including as web app on mobile device's web browser).

So will start to unpick the full app's Widget Tree and try to figure out where in the tree the issue is being made to occur. NOTE: There are various `Column` and other widgets in between the `Scaffold` and `NameWidget` in the full blown app.

Comment: Can you clarify where exactly you have problem? Because you mentioned that editing works fine on mobile and tablets, then on web but later **On mobile web browser however, app's TextField editing fails**

Comment: @powerman23rus the s/w keyboard fails when the app runs as a web app on a mobile device's web browser. But the s/w keyboard does work when the app is run natively on a mobile device as a packaged app.